# Run a non-jRuby project after installing jRuby (or remove jRuby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I installed jRuby to try it in a new project, but I didn't think it would affect my entire Ruby installation.

Now when I try to start an old project, I get an error

```
/usr/bin/env jruby: no such file or directory
```

I've tried searching for how to remove jruby, but don't come up with anything. is there a nice way to get my rails apps working again with regular ruby?

I REALLY hope so.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it created symlinks; point them back at at the Ruby you want to use.

[Use something like `rvm` to avoid this](http://beginrescueend.com/). (Or [`rbenv` if you prefer](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).)

Comment: I use rvm, and ran rvm uninstall jruby, but I am still getting the error. Can you explain where I would find the 'symlinks'?

Comment: @pedalpete If you're using rvm, set yourself back to the ruby you want to use. Check for an .rvmrc file; perhaps the project in question had one to force JRuby.

Comment: the project I'm trying to run never used jruby, but for some reason I'm getting this error. I don't see any .rvmrc files anywhere. I've gone through my configuration files, etc. etc and nowhere do I see any reference to jruby. I just rolled back the server to a previous state (vmware), and I still get the same jruby not found error.

Comment: @pedalpete I don't know how you installed JRuby. You'll need to use `which rails`, `which ruby`, etc. to track down where the links are, if they're symlinks, etc. If you've used rvm properly, you should be able to use it to switch to a different ruby.

Comment: thanks dave, that lead me part of the way there. I found the link to jruby through which rails - <pre>#!/usr/bin/env jruby</pre> and edited taht to 'ruby', though I don't know if that is what I'm supposed to do. The whole app just hangs now when trying to run the server :(

Comment: @pedalpete Personally, I'd start all over using `rvm` properly, not under `sudo`, and ignore all these issues.

Comment: you mean rebuild the server? I'm surprised that there isn't an easier way to get rid of jRuby

Comment: @pedalpete Uh, no; blow away your `.rvm` directory, update to the latest `rvm` version, and reinstall your Rubies.

Answer (score 1):

Rerun "bundle install" -- if you ran bundle install under jruby, the shebang for your scripts in the /bin folder was likely changed to reference jruby. By re-running bundle install under MRI, bundler will fix the shebangs for you.